# Return response according to a common json schema

Tags: node.js, express, microservices, express-gateway

How can I make standard json keys schema for multiple API service.

What if on original response I want to map to specific keys?
Maybe adding or removing keys too?

I'd like to have same json keys output for all api services
for example: api service output:

```
{ "hello" : "word" }
```

but i want to response:

```
{"foo" : originalResponse.hello }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why the downvotes, the question seems legit to me.

In any case, you can achieve the use case by using the [body modifier](https://github.com/XVincentX/express-gateway-plugin-body-modifier) plugin we offer. Although it's not an official one, it should provide all you need to both add are move keys on a JSON payload based on any Javascript evaluable expression.

Cheers!

Comment: Seems the right answer according to what i can read from the README (i will test tonight). Thanks!!! It would be amazing if it can takes json schema file path, but probably impossibile to do the "diff" operation between the schema and the response.